# LinkedIn Company Page created using private or business account?

Tags: linkedin

I have to create a LinkedIn Company Page but I only have my private account on LinkedIn. If I use my private account to create Linked Company Page, will anyone be able to see that I created it?

If it's like on Facebook where no one can see who created Facebook Page (except admins of the page), then I will use my private account.

I don't have business account on LinkedIn and I would not like to create and maintain it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no one will be able to see that you have created that page. There is no way within LinkedIn to see lists of admins for Company pages, or even one admin for one page. This is an "internal" setting that only the admin(s) of that page can see.

And to create a company page you need to have a personal LinkedIn profile.

From Help Center [Adding a Company Page](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/710/~/adding-a-company-page):

> Before starting, you must own a personal LinkedIn profile